# C++ add virtual method in polymorphic subclass

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have cumbersome class and I want to refactor it to replace type code with subclasses. At some point during such process I have following hierarchy:

```
// interface
ISomeClass(){
public:
    virtual foo() = 0;
    virtual ~ISomeClass();
}


// this class is cumbersome one with huge amount of conditional logic based on type
BaseSomeClass : public ISomeClass(){
public:
    virtual foo(){
       if(TYPE_0 == getType()){   // finally I want to move such conditional logic in subclass
           doSmth();
       } else if (TYPE_1 == getType()){
           doAnother();
       }
    }


protected:
    virtual int getType(){     // I temporary need it for refactoring issue 
        return type_;          // to replace type_ with subclasses
    }

private:
    int type_;

};

// this classes is almost empty now, but I want to move there all conditional logic in future
class Implementation1 : public BaseSomeClass {
     virtual int getType(){    // I temporary need it for refactoring issue 
        return TYPE_0;         // to replace type_ with subclasses
    }
}; 


class Implementation2 : public BaseSomeClass {
     virtual int getType(){    // I temporary need it for refactoring issue 
        return TYPE_1;         // to replace type_ with subclasses
    }
};
```

In `BaseSomeClass`defined additional virtual method `getType()`. Would this method behavior be polymorphic if I handle all the instances using some kind of interface `ISomeClass` pointer? Assuming the interface itself doesn't provide such virtual method. **Please** notice this code is a first step in refactoring, not final one. Also this is a simplified example and real code has tens of such methods, I need to do refactoring step by step. And the question is about C++ dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: Sounds to me like `Implementation1` and `Implementation2` should not be part of `ISomeClass`'s hierarchy at all, but completely seperate types.

Comment: Why won't you just overload `foo()` ? Even if `doSmth` and `doAnother` have to be defined in `BaseSomeClass` (for which currently is no reason), you could do `Impl1::foo(){Base::doSmth()};` and `Impl2::foo(){Base::doAnother()};`.

Comment: Your question is very clear. It should be easy for you to ask the compiler.

Comment: It seems it is a good first step to remove ugly code from `foo()`

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, this is a first step only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked:

> Would this method behavior be polymorphic if I handle all the instances using some kind of interface `ISomeClass` pointer? Assuming the interface itself doesn't provide such virtual method.

If the interface does not provide such a virtual method, you can't expect polymorphic behavior.

It'll be better to implement `foo` in `Implementation1` and `Implementation2`.

```
class BaseSomeClass : public ISomeClass()
{
};

class Implementation1 : public BaseSomeClass 
{
   virtual void foo()
   {
      doSmth();
   }
}; 


class Implementation2 : public BaseSomeClass
{
   virtual void foo()
   {
      doAnother();
   }
};
```

If you must use `getType()`, you can resort to template based polymorphic behavior.

```
template <typename D>
class BaseSomeClass : public ISomeClass()
{
   public:
      virtual foo()
      {
         int type = D::getType();
         if(TYPE_0 == type)
         {
            doSmth();
         }
         else if (TYPE_1 == type)
         {
            doAnother();
         }
      }
};
```

Here, you are expecting `D` to provide the interface `getType()`. You might as well expect `D` to provide the interface `foo`.

```
template <typename D>
class BaseSomeClass : public ISomeClass()
{
   public:
      virtual void foo()
      {
         D::foo():
      }
};
```

Comment: This is what I want to reach finally, this code is only a snapshot during such safe step-by-step refactoring

Comment: @vard So you want to keep iterating through ugly code, just to run tests, instead of going straight for a proper solution? I'm not sure if this is the good idea.

Comment: @luk32 this code is very simplified to real code I have, just to illustrate question, which is about dynamic polymorphism details.